# OWL Carousel: center slide if click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm just wondering if there is a way to easily center a slide if I click on it.
So the clicked slide moves to the middle.

Here is my code. The "center on click" function should work on the first slide called "#singleprice".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var $sync1 = $("#singleprice"),
        $sync2 = $("#meanprice"),
        flag = false,
        duration = 300;

    $sync1
        .owlCarousel({
        nav: true,
        items: '3',
        startPosition: '4',
        dots: false,
        center: true,
        navContainer: '#priceNav',
        })
        .on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;
                $sync2.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, duration, true]);
                flag = false;
            }
        });


    $sync2
        .owlCarousel({
        nav: false,
        items: '1',
        startPosition: '4',
        touchDrag: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
        dots: false
        })
        .on('click', '.owl-item', function () {
            $sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), duration, true]);

        })
        .on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;        
                $sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, duration, true]);
                flag = false;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: You can use `owl.goTo(x)  // Go to x slide` when you click on an item.